# View numeric columns in hex - SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server Management Studio, when I run a query which outputs a numeric column (int or similar types), they are displayed in decimal (example: 193). I want them to display in hex (example: 0xC1). How do I do that?

I found many answers on how to write converter functions, but I don't want that - only change the display in SSMS. I only found [this unanswered question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/f347c595-3e6c-4c4d-a0e3-f91975785472/).

I use SQL Server Management Studio 2008, though may move to SQL Server 2012 soon.